# Polynomial to the power n algorithm

Tags: algorithm, polynomial-math

Which is the best way to do polynomial powers? Is it by following the multinomial theorem ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)) which takes O(?) or by FFT (fast Fourier transformation) and then inverse FFT with O((N*log(N))^2)?

Comment: could you make an example? what do you want to calculate?

Comment: Best in what way? And what size/order are the problems? There is likely not one best answer; for example, for a small problem, the straight-forward brute-force multiplication can be faster than using an FFT-based algorithm, because the initial setup of the algorithm isn't worth the speedup. But for huge problems, an FFT approach would definitely be worth it...

Comment: Why do you think FFT + inverse FFT is O((N log(N))^2)? Both are O(N log(N)) so their sum is also O(N log(N)).

Comment: Yes, it's O(N Log(N)). I know that FFT and inverse-FFT is the best way to multiply poly P with Q but if you want an algorithm just to power P (ex: P^n) is the FFT and iFFT still the best way to go? What I'm trying to calculate is a poly of degree 12 in which its power can go from 2 to 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFT if you need to do it frequently, or on large polynomials. The naive multiplication algorithm is **O(N^2)**, while FFT is **O(N log(N))**.

Here is a much better explanation with some neat applications: [JeffE FFT](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/02-fft.pdf)

Comment: With N=k*deg(p) in both cases if p(z)^k is to be computed. If you want to compute the polynomial that has the powers of roots of p as its roots, use Dandelin-Graeffe iteration or for non-dyadic powers, the Newton identities between power sums of roots and polynomial coefficients.